# /usr/bin/env: pythone Agreement (BSD License)

Tags: python

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the Core ROS Tutorials - Examining the Simple Publisher and Subscriber, when I am running the Subscriber

```
$ rosrun beginner_tutorials listener.py
```

it returns

```
/usr/bin/env: pythone Agreement (BSD License): No such file or directory
```

why?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/216765//usr/bin/env:-pythone-agreement-(bsd-license)/) by [mgangster](https://answers.ros.org/users/23721/mgangster/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-08-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looks like the first line of listener.py has been corrupted. The first line of a script usually has a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29). It's a hint that tells your shell which program it should use to execute the script. /usr/bin/env is complaining because it was asked to find a program called "pythone Agreement (BSD License)"

Since it's been corrupted it's probably best to download the file again. If you instead want to try to fix it then edit listener.py so the very first line is this.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

This tells your shell to use /usr/bin/env to find python and have it run this script.

---

Originally posted by [sloretz](https://answers.ros.org/users/23470/sloretz/) with karma: 3061 on 2015-09-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2